# convert a text to a number

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why this code doesn't work ..i wanna just convert text to number .. It doesn't give me any error but it doesn't work

```
Public Function ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber(ByVal chain As String) As Integer

 Select Case chain
        Case "1 - Très difficile"
            ConvertCOMPLEXITYTToNumber = 1
        Case "2 - Difficile"
            ConvertCOMPLEXITYTToNumber = 2
        Case "3 - Modérée"
            ConvertCOMPLEXITYTToNumber = 3
        Case "4 - Facile"
            ConvertCOMPLEXITYTToNumber = 4
        Case Else
            ConvertCOMPLEXITYTToNumber = 0
    End Select

    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you just trim the leftmost character of the string to get the number?

Comment: I think that only four item is valid for use.

Answer (score 1):

That may be because you may have unwanted leading or trailing spaces which fails the comparison. Also you do not need `Exit Function` at the end of the code. It will exit any ways :)

Try this

```
Public Function ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber(ByVal chain As String) As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer

    Select Case Trim(chain)
        Case "1 - Très difficile": Num = 1
        Case "2 - Difficile": Num = 2
        Case "3 - Modérée": Num = 3
        Case "4 - Facile": Num = 4
        Case Else: Num = 0
    End Select

    ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber = Num
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If IsNumeric(Left(Trim(chain),1)) Then
    ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber = Left(Trim(chain),1)
Else
    ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber = 0
End If
```

Comment: What if the `Chain = "1 - Très Sid"`?

Comment: or `Chain = "2-Excel Developers"` In such scenarios, the value of `ConvertCOMPLEXITYTToNumber` should be `0` but if you look at left number then you will get incorrect results :)

Comment: Ah, yes, if those are possibilities then my answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here, my approach for you:

```
Public Function ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber(ByVal chain As String) As Integer

    'Get the first character
    chain = Left(Trim(chain), 1)

    'If frist character is numeric
    If IsNumeric(chain) Then

        'If first number is less than 5, return value
        If chain < 5 Then
            ConvertCOMPLEXITYToNumber = CInt(chain)
        End If

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: How is this different than what Excel Developers Posted? :)

Comment: Actually, his code not work well, I do this for code clear and easily understandable. My logic is `1. Get the first char`, `2. IF not a numberic, it will return 0 by default`, `3. If less than 5, return by changing integer type`. I already tested and it work well.

Comment: did you see my comment below his post?

Comment: Yes I know, I am giving reference for condition like data has no duplicate first char. I think so, I did it. If there is no duplicate, my way is good. If not, your way is good. I just want to show different usage.